# Is this a good practice to bundle all css and js script loadings in an asp.net user control?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms

As much as I develop an asp.net web forms project, more and more css and javascript files become needed to load in every page. Beside, There are also some conditional statements like

```
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
```

So the question is: Is this a good practice to bundle all css and js script loadings in an asp.net user control and then putting only that user control in page header instead of adding all those lines to every page/masterpage?

Your solutions are appreciated.

Comment: As you are using MasterPages, why not use them nested? The parent one can hold all of this.

Comment: I'm using them but still there are many master pages and I want to minimize modifications when new features that require style/script loading are being added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been a practice with user controls: to bundle resources (js, css, images) with the control in order to make it self-contained.

However, main problem that arises out of this is that the resources can't get cached on the client-side and hence are loaded every time that page is requested. Moreover, if multiple controls use some or all of the resources, then they are loaded multiple times and code reuse is defeated.

You will have to weigh in your options carefully. If your app is relying too much on user-controls then you have to live with that. You can identify common resources and separate them out and load them in pages where required.

I would suggest identifying common resources and bundling them (using tools or manually) into one file and load in individual pages (or master page as appropriate) and do a js minify. Typically css goes in head and js goes at the end of page.

Bundling everything in a single user-control will give problems of maintainability, version control and of course caching as mentioned above.

With regard to css specifically, I would suggest that you use ASP.Net themes (stylesheet themes). That way all styles remain in one place and provide easy customization options.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive and covering answer.